# Passing a struct pointer to a function in C to dereference an array

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm having an issue with trying to pass a struct pointer to a function that sets the pointer to point to a particular row of a multidimensional array.

This is the declaration of the struct:

```
typedef struct PartitionInfoStruct
{
   Partition definition;
   u16 start;
   u16 size;
   StringLiteral* desc;
} PartitionInfo;
```

Here is the function:

```
void readPartitionTable(Partition partition, PartitionInfo* partitionInfo)
{
   switch(installedFlashDevice)
   {
      case S25FL032P:
         partitionInfo = &PARTITION_TABLE_S25FL032P[partition];
         break;
      case SST26VF032B:
         partitionInfo = &PARTITION_TABLE_SST26VF032B[partition];
         break;
      default:
      //do nothing
         break;
   }   

   ASSERT(partitionInfo != NULL);     
}
```

And this is the call I am making:

```
 PartitionInfo* partitionInfo = NULL;
 readPartitionTable((Partition)counter, partitionInfo);
```

For some reason when calling `readPartitionTable`, and then dereferencing `partitionInfo` afterwards, I am not getting the required results - namely, the ASSERT fails.

Comment: The assert *inside* the function fails? You're sure `counter` is either `S25FL032P` or `SST26VF032B`?  You have another problem, though: you're only assigning to the local copy of the pointer inside the function, which will have no effect on the pointer passed in by the caller...

Comment: _calling readPartitionTable, and then dereferencing partitionInfo afterwards_ You mean afterwards after it cames from function or assert in function fails?

Comment: @aschepler: Why "*`counter`*"? The argument to the switch is `installedFlashDevice`.

Comment: Please provide the definitions of `Partition` and `StringLiteral`.

Comment: If the `ASSERT` failed you would not be able to do anything "*afterwards*" as the program most likely would have ended immediately.

Comment: @alk Good point, missed that.

Comment: aschepler has it right! I am expecting a local copy of a pointer to be global. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when calling readPartitionTable, and *then dereferencing partitionInfo
>   afterwards*, I am not getting the required results - namely, the ASSERT
>   fails

If you're dereferencing `partitionInfo` after calling `readPartitionTable`, that's outside of your function, so it's not the `assert` that's failing.

The problem is that your function is changing the *value* of a parameter, i.e. `partitionInfo`.  After the assignment, the `assert` succeeds, however changes to a local variable or parameter are not visible outside of the function.

What you can do however is take a pointer as a parameter and *dereference* it.  Then you can read/write what it points to, namely a variable in another function.  So pass in a `PartitionInfo **`, i.e. the address of a `PartitionInfo *` to do this:

```
void readPartitionTable(Partition partition, PartitionInfo **partitionInfo)
{
   switch(installedFlashDevice)
   {
      case S25FL032P:
         *partitionInfo = &PARTITION_TABLE_S25FL032P[partition];
         break;
      case SST26VF032B:
         *partitionInfo = &PARTITION_TABLE_SST26VF032B[partition];
         break;
      default:
      //do nothing
         break;
   }   

   ASSERT(*partitionInfo != NULL);     
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
 PartitionInfo* partitionInfo = NULL;
 readPartitionTable((Partition)counter, &partitionInfo);
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It would mind, if @PeterJ didnt instadownvoted all my answers since i told him he shouldnt do placeholders. Ye we should remove these comments.

Comment: @makepeace Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.